How to level uneven concrete garage floor? (20x26, 25 yrs old, undamaged, no cracks, plus/minus half inch variation from average, one expansion joint)
I'm obviously considering self-levelling underlayment. But open to any "relatively DIY" suggestions. Or any warnings against self-levelling underlayment? Simply put, what do you think I should do to level the floor?
I will cover the levelled surface with new VCT tiles that I have in abundance.
There will be occasional cars, but garage will be mostly used for my shop. I have some relatively heavy machinery that requires stability and good levelling. I don't want to level casters all the time when I'll have to move machines.
I checked with flooring companies around that do garages, but they either focus on residential garages to fix cracks and coat it shiny, or professional shops that pay 10s of K for precision levelling -- nothing much in between. So this is up to me! :)
Thanks!
PS: On strong ground, no sweating, or any other issues or structural weaknesses I can diagnose

Primer, make sure you use plenty of primer so the leveling concrete sticks

There is a reason the garage floor is sloped. In some regions it is not just for water. A garage attached to a home must have the floor that slopes away from the living area of the structure.  Leveling the floor may be a violation of local building code.  This is so any combustible fluids leaking from a vehicle run away from the living areas and not towards it.

I appreciate you pointing that out, especially for others reading these questions and comments. But my garage is not sloped. It's just subpar workmanship (and very minor movement of the soil over the years) that caused multiple high and low points, which in turn causes problems for me. I'm trying to even them out, that's all. Thanks.
